# frequency <unordered_map> behaviour

Tags: c++

i try to implement freq unordered map but it has weird behavior , why when i use unordered_map it gives me keys with negative numbers and when i use map it will give my the correct keys values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int maxOperations(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        unordered_map <int,int> mp;
        for(auto i:nums){
            mp[i]++;
        }
        int count=0;
       // for(auto i:mp)
          //  cout << i.first << " " << i.second << endl;

        for(auto i:mp){
            int target= k-i.first;
            cout << i.first << " " << i.second << "  "<< mp[target] << endl;
            if(i.second>0 && mp[target]>0){
                if(i.first!=target){
                    count += min(i.second,mp[target]);

                    mp[target]=0;
                    //i.second=0;
                    mp[i.first]=0;
                }else
                {
                    cout <<  count << endl;
                    count += floor(i.second/2);
                    mp[target]=0;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;}


int main()
{
    vector<int> vec= {29,26,81,70,75,4,48,38,22,10,51,62,17,50,7,7,24,61,54,44,30,29,66,83,6,45,24,49,42,31,10,6,88,48,34,10,54,56,80,41,19};
    int k =12 ;
    cout << maxOperations(vec,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mp[target]=0;` will create a negative key when `target` is a negative number, which occurs in your input most of the time (`29` is greater than `12`, for instance.) I'm not really following what the second `for` loop is doing, or what you expect the output to be for your input. Can you explain what should be happening and what is happening instead?

Comment: What may be happening is that you're experiencing some side effects from mutating the contents of `mp` while iterating over it. `mp[target] = 0` will add a new key to `mp` if `target` wasn't already a key, which it often wasn't. Because `map` and `unordered_map` will iterate over their contents in different orders, you're seeing the results of adding those keys in the `unordered_map` version but not the `map` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an ordered map, you traverse the keys in order. Thus, `target` is never negative. When you traverse an unordered map, it is unordered. Therefore, `target` is sometimes negative.

If the negative values are not correct, then you need to traverse the map in order and so you should not use an unordered map.

Another problem with traversing out of order is that when modifying the map while traversing it, you will create entries that may or may not be included in your traversal. That will cause unpredictable behavior. You may prefer to create new entries in a separate container and merge them into the original container only when you're finished traversing.

Comment: `target` is still negative when `i.first` is greater than `k` no matter what order you traverse the map.

Comment: but with map the issue is solved , negative numbers will never appear even if k<i.first

Comment: The negative numbers don't _appear_ because the order of traversal is different, but they still exist. Essentially when you're adding members to a container while you're iterating over it, you get different behavior depending on whether they get put in "the part of the container I have yet to traverse" or "the part of the container I already took a look at". `unordered_map` is giving you the first, `map` gives you the second because it sorts on keys.